# upload update versio without version1 images

Tags: c#, deployment, visual-studio-2012, clickonce, publishing

Visual Studio 2012 - C#

I published my project on a site and have enabled the update function. The project includes approximately 1500 images. It takes a long time until they are all uploaded on the server. The picture files will not change, however, in future updates. How can you upload an updated version without all the images, so that the user can update the application Launch automatically?

Edit:
the publish works, however, are on every version all pictures uploaded again

Comment: What is your project type? Desktop application?

Comment: @M Sakher Sawan Desktop application

Comment: yes, using Click-Once deployment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using ClickOnce deployment, You can develop your own deplyment package using the very helpful tool :

[Bootstrapper Manifest Generator](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/bmg)

Put your images in some SFX archive (for example) and develop your own package and set a conditions for it (To prevent it from being downloaded to the clients every time) and set this new package as a prerequisite for your application, now, clients should press "Install" button instead of "Lunch" link to run your application and install this package to there machines.